# How to use PostgreSQL ILIKE in query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to use `ILIKE` in my query to find my result.

In my **tbl_customers** I have 3 columns : `first_name, last_name, national_code`

I send a value as string that contain all parameter like this: `'name lastname 1234910'`

Here is my query :

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, 
    concat(t1.first_name, ' ', t1.last_name) as full_name,
    t1.national_code,
    row_number() over (order by t1.published_at desc)
    
    FROM tbl_customers as t1 RIGHT JOIN tbl_ticketings as t2  ON t1.id = 
        t2.customer_id 
    WHERE  (
     (t1.first_name ILIKE '%'|| _customer_info || '%') OR (t1.last_name 
     ILIKE '%'|| _customer_info || '%') 
       OR (t1.national_code ILike '%'|| _customer_info || '%')
         )
    Group BY t1.id
    ORDER BY 
    t1.published_at desc
```

The variable `_customer_info` is equal to `'name lastname 1234910'`

When I run this query I get nothing.

I changed `_customer_info` , `'name'` , `'lastname'` , `'1234910'`  sepratly, I get the result but I don't want use like that.

I don't have any syntax errors, I know my `ILIKE` query haa a problem;
what is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You have something like:

```
WHERE '1234910' ILIKE '%name lastname 1234910%'
```

You want it vice versa:

```
WHERE 'name lastname 1234910' ILIKE '%1234910%'
```

I suggest not to muddle through with `ILIKE` here, though. Split your variable into its three parts and compare directly. This is faster and safer.

```
WHERE t1.first_name    = REGEXP_SUBSTR(_customer_info, '[^ ]+', 1, 1)
   OR t1.last_name     = REGEXP_SUBSTR(_customer_info, '[^ ]+', 1, 2)
   OR t1.national_code = REGEXP_SUBSTR(_customer_info, '[^ ]+', 1, 3)
```

Comment: what is regexp_substr equivalent in postgresql ?

Comment: This *is* PostgreSQL. I found it here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html. They say, it's only available in PostgreSQL 15 and up, though. But well, this is just some string manipulation. The same can be done with `SUBSTR`/ `SUBSTRING` and `POSITION` / `STRPOS`.